# QTP v 10.0 on windows 7 - need to solve the issue with getVisibleText

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, gettext, qtp

On Windows XP getVisibleText was working fine in scripts.
After migration to QTP10 and Windows 7 was done they stopped to work.

Is there a good workaround for that issue? (migration to QTP11 is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation in QTP due to changes in Windows 7.
A quick search finds [this thread](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=609430&an=&page=&vc=1) which quotes from a [KB](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM817982).

> Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 do not support the
>      Windows API test recognition mechanism.  Therefore, when
>      you install this patch, the **'Use text recognition
>      mechanisms in this order'** option in the Options dialog
>      box (**Tools > Options > Text Recognition**) is set to **'Use
>      only OCR'**, and cannot be changed (the option is
>      disabled).

I believe there is a typo and it should read *teXt recognition*  instead of *teSt recognition*.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue since many day and finally got the very very good alternative to that.

Using this alternative you can work without depending on Window version.

You may see my full implementation at the below link

http://qtpissues.blogspot.com/2013/03/alternative-to-getvisibletext-function.html